# changing an immutable object in python, methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I know integers are immutable, how would I go about printing 4 instead of 2?

```
a = 2
def add(num):
   num = 4
print(a)
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in this code example? What's your endgame here?

Comment: Just because the integer itself is immutable, that doesn't stop you assigning a different integer reference to `a`. Is that what you are asking? It's not very clear, your question is lacking detail.

Comment: add a line `return num` to your `add` method

Comment: Function parameters are passed by value, not by reference. You can't change the caller's variable from a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, variables are just baskets that hold values. If you want `a` to hold a different value, just put it in. Simple as that.

```
a = 2 # value
a = 3 # new value
```

Although the integer 2 is immutable, `a` is just an object reference to that integer. `a` itself - the object reference- can be changed to reference any object at any time.

As you have discovered, you can't simply pass a variable to a function and change its value:

```
def f(a):
    a = 4
f(a)
print(a) # still 3
```

Why still 3? Because in Python objects are passed by * object reference*. This is neither the same as by value, nor is it the same as by reference, in other languages.

The `a` inside of the function is a different object reference than outside of the function. It's a different namespace. If you want to change the function so that its `a` is the other, final `a`, you have to explicitly specify that this is what you want.

```
def f():
    global a # this makes any following references to a refer to the global namespace
    a = 4
f()
print (a) # 4
```

I highly recommend [this link](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) for further reading.

Comment: Or process a mutable type: `def f(a):`  `    a[0]=5` `L=[3]` `f(L)` `print(L[0])`  -  a bit convoluted, but it serves as a decent example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
a = 2
def add():
    global a
    a = 4

add()
print(a)
```

The `add()` function will change a's value to 4 and the output would be 4.